# Evaluate the complex line integral $\int_\gamma\frac{z^5}{z^7+3z-10}\,dz$, $\gamma$ is the boundary of $D(0,2)$ oriented counterclockwise

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

This is a UW Madison analysis qualifying exam problem.

I think if $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $|z|\geq 2$ then $|z^7+3z-10|\geq|z|^7-3|z|-10>0$, so we can take $\gamma$ to be the boundary of $D(0,R)$ for any $R>2$. Let $R\rightarrow\infty$ we see that the integral should be $0$.

Is my reasoning correct? Thanks!

Comment: Unless you want to use residue at infinity in a clearer way I can't understand why $\;R\to\infty\;$ is relevant here to deduce  the value of an integral on canionical circle of radius two...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since the poles are all in the disk of radius two, $\partial D(0, 2)$ is homotopic to $\partial D(0, R)$ for all $R \geq 2$ relative to the domain $\mathbb C \setminus \{\text{poles}\}$. And contour integration is homotopy invariant, therefore
$$\int_{\partial D(0, 2)} \frac{z^5}{z^7 + 3z - 10}dz = \int_{\partial D(0, R)} \frac{z^5}{z^7 + 3z - 10}dz \sim \frac1R \overset{R \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0.$$

Comment: How do you get that $\;\sim\cfrac1R\;$ ??

Comment: the integrand looks like $\frac{1}{R^2}$, the contour length is $2\pi R$, so the integral looks like $\frac{1}{R}$ if $R$ is large.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that  $\;f(z)=\cfrac{z^5}{z^7+3z-10}\;$ has only simple poles at the roots of the denominator, thus

$$\int_{D(0,2)}f(z)\,dz=2\pi i\text{ Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac1{z^2}f\left(\frac1z\right)\right)=2\pi i\text{ Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac1{z^2}\cdot\frac{\frac1{z^5}}{\frac1{z^7}+\frac3z-10}\right)=$$

$$=2\pi i\text{ Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac1{z^2}\cdot\frac{z^2}{1+3z^6-10z^7}\right)=2\pi i\text{ Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac1{1+3z^6-10z^7}\right)=0$$

since $\;\cfrac1{1+3z^6-10z^7}\;$ is analytic at zero...

Perhaps you meant something like the above in your question but I didn't see it clearly.

Comment: What I meant was if $|z|=R$, then the numerator looks like $R^5$ if $R$ is large, the denominator looks like $R^7$ when $R$ is large. So the integrand looks like $\frac{1}{R^2}$ if $R$ is large. So the integral goes to zero like $\frac{1}{R^2}2\pi R$.

Comment: But how will you pass from a complex variable $\;z\;$ to the real $\;R\;$ to do the evaluation as a limit? I can't see it, even using the LN theorem...

Comment: Use the estimation $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz\leq \text{length}\gamma\cdot\sup_{z\in\gamma}|f(z)|$

Comment: @Simplyorange That's the estimation lemma I was talking about. How do you get $#\;R\;$ into that estimation and then how does taking the limit $\;R\to0\;$ fits into waht you want? Ahd observe the same question is relevant in the answer you accepted...but if that satisfies you then all is fine...

Comment: I meant let $R$ goes to $\infty$.